# How to prefetch a count and use it to annotate a queryset in Django ORM

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I’m trying to perform an advanced SQL query but I can’t figure out how to do this.
My goal is to implement a read/unread system for a Forum, so i have the followings models (incomplete for :
succinctness)

```
class ReadActivity(models.Model):
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    reader = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False)
    read_until = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False, default=timezone.now)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("content_type", "object_id", "reader"),)

class Readable(models.Model):
    read_activities = GenericRelation(ReadActivity)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Forum(models.Model):
    pass
class Topic(Readable):
    pass
```

I think this is quite self explanatory : Topics can be marked as read. A user has zero or one ReadActivity per topic. (In fact Forum is also readable but this is out of scope for this question)

So : I want to be able to fetch a forum list, and for each forum determine if it is read or unread (for a given user)
My approach is :
For each forums, if any topic do not have any ReadActivity or a ReadActivity where read_until < last_message, mark the forum as unread.

Speaking SQL, I would do that this in the following way :

```
SELECT COUNT("forums_topic"."id")
FROM "forums_topic"
  LEFT JOIN "reads_readactivity"
    ON ("forums_topic"."id" = "reads_readactivity"."object_id" AND "reads_readactivity"."content_type_id" = '11')
WHERE (("reads_readactivity"."id" IS NULL
        OR ("reads_readactivity"."reader_id" = '1' AND "reads_readactivity"."read_until" < "forums_topic”."last_message_date"))
       AND "forums_topic"."forum_id" IN ('1', '2'))
GROUP BY "forums_topic"."forum_id"
```

But I can’t find a way to do this using Django ORM (Without many many queries). I tried to use Prefetch :

```
topics_prefetch = Topic.objects.filter(Q(read_activities=None) | (Q(read_activities__reader=self.request.user) & Q(read_activities__read_until__gt=F('created_at'))))
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(Prefetch('read_activities', queryset=ReadActivity.objects.filter(reader=self.request.user)))
```

But this solution is not good enough, because there is no way I can select COUNT(), or limit to 1 result, and group the count by forum.

I tried to combine this solution with annotate :

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(is_unread=Count('topics__read_activities’))
```

But this just don’t work, it counts ALL the topics

Then I tried to use annotate with case/when :

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(is_unread=Case(
    When(topics=None, then=False),
    When(topics__read_activities=None, then=True),
    When(topics__read_activities__reader=self.request.user, topics__read_activities__read_until__lte=F('topics__created_at'), then=True),
    default=False,
    output_field=BooleanField()
))
```

But it does not give the right results. Moreover I’m not sure this is the best solution. I’m not sure how CASE/WHEN SQL are implemented, but if it iterates internally on every topics, this may be too expensive

Now I’m considering writing RawSQL, however I don’t know how to add a manager method which would let be do something like : Forums.objects.filter().with_unread(), because I don’t know how to access the filtered forums to build a query like 
"forums_topic"."forum_id" IN ('1', '2'))
 from the manager itself.

Maybe I’m missing something, maybe you know how to do that. Any help would be appreciated, thank you !